# horizontal scroll DIV with buttons

Tags: javascript, html

Not sure what I am doing wrong, I want de content of this DIV scroll horizontaly when I press the buttons. Got a lot of code from here, but now i'm stuck.....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Naamloos document</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style>
#browser { float: left; width: 400px; overflow: auto; white-space: nowrap; }


</style>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" class="leftArrow" value="left">
```

This is the DIV that should scroll

```
<div id="browser">
  <div class="innerWrapper">
      <div style="background-color:#0CC; width:200px; height:200px; display:inline-block"></div>
      <div style="background-color:#0FC; width:200px; height:200px; display:inline-block"></div>
      <div style="background-color:#3CF; width:200px; height:200px; display:inline-block"></div>
      <div style="background-color:#0CC; width:200px; height:200px; display:inline-block"></div>
      <div style="background-color:#0CC; width:200px; height:200px; display:inline-block"></div>
      <div style="background-color:#0FC; width:200px; height:200px; display:inline-block"></div>
      <div style="background-color:#3CF; width:200px; height:200px; display:inline-block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button"  class="rightArrow" value="right">
```

I'm not sure if I should put my script here

```
<!--
<script>
   $('#right-button').click(function() {
      var leftPos = $('#content').scrollLeft();
      $('#content').animate({scrollLeft: leftPos - 200}, 800);
   });

      $('#left-button').click(function() {
        var leftPos = $('#content').scrollLeft();
      $('#content').animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 200}, 800);
   });
</script>
-->

</body>
</html>
```

link to 
[DEMO](http://kop.hosts.ma-cloud.nl/scroll-div/)

Answer (score 2):

I got this working. New mark-up and script below.

Some issues you had:

- The jQuery script was not wrapped in a "document ready" handler.
- Various mismatched naming issues between your classes and ids.

Hope this helps (tested it locally):

```
  <div id="outer">
     <div id="inner">
        <div style="background-color:#0CC; width:200px; height:200px; display:inline-block"></div>
        <div style="background-color:#0FC; width:200px; height:200px; display:inline-block"></div>
        <div style="background-color:#3CF; width:200px; height:200px; display:inline-block"></div>
        <div style="background-color:#0CC; width:200px; height:200px; display:inline-block"></div>
        <div style="background-color:#0CC; width:200px; height:200px; display:inline-block"></div>
        <div style="background-color:#0FC; width:200px; height:200px; display:inline-block"></div>
        <div style="background-color:#3CF; width:200px; height:200px; display:inline-block"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="left-button" class="leftArrow" value="left">
  <input type="button" id="right-button" class="rightArrow" value="right">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
     $(function () {
        var outer = $('#outer');

        $('#right-button').click(function () {
           var leftPos = outer.scrollLeft();
           outer.animate({ scrollLeft: leftPos - 200 }, 800);
        });

        $('#left-button').click(function () {
           var leftPos = outer.scrollLeft();
           outer.animate({ scrollLeft: leftPos + 200 }, 800);
        });
     });
  </script>
```

And slightly renamed style:

```
<style>
   #outer {
      float: left;
      width: 400px;
      overflow: auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: You may need to flip the "left" and "right" button logic. Currently at startup, if you click "Left" it scrolls the viewport to the right.

Answer (score 1):

1)#right-button and #left-button missing in your both buttons.so use with class

2)use ready function for event handler.

3)use #browser instead #conten.because there is no id with this name.

4)use +200 for right and -200 for left in animate.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.rightArrow').click(function() {
          var leftPos = $('#content').scrollLeft();
          $('#browser').animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 200}, 800);
       });

          $('.leftArrow').click(function() { 
            var leftPos = $('#content').scrollLeft();
          $('#browser').animate({scrollLeft: leftPos - 200}, 800);
       });
          });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#right-button` would refer to a tag with `id='#right-button'`
try '`.rightArrow`' instead ;)
(or change in the input tag `class` by `id`, and use the right names)

Then put your script in the between `<head></head>`

Also, you are using scrollLeft, wich control the "scroll" that's means tou can use it on elements with overflow to scroll.

If you want to move, you should consider `.offset` or `.position`, and also `.animate` to add a visual effect

Comment: I agree that you can use `.offset` and `.position`, but it also works with `.animate` and `.scrollLeft`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have your script commented and it's also not pointing to the correct ids/classes. 
Also, you had the arrows going the opposite ways.

Here's how it should look like for the HTML you posted

```
<script>
   $('.rightArrow').click(function() {
      var leftPos = $('#browser').scrollLeft();
      $('#browser').animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 200}, 800);
   });

      $('.leftArrow').click(function() {
      var leftPos = $('#browser').scrollLeft();
      $('#browser').animate({scrollLeft: leftPos - 200}, 800);
   });
</script>
```

Also, while you can put `<script>` elements inside the `body`, it would be better to add them to the `head` section instead.